# Is there anyway to automate additions of batch dims?

Tags: python, numpy, automation

I'm wanting to automate the addition of 1 extra dimension to a numpy array. How should I set this up?

EDIT:

```
#TODO: This feels like it could be automated...
def add_batch(arr):
    if arr.ndim == 2:
        arr = np.reshape(arr, (arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], 1))
    elif arr.ndim == 3:
        arr = np.reshape(arr, (arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1], arr.shape[2], 1))
```

Comment: Both `if` and `elif` contains the same operation. What is different here? You can simply use `if arr.ndim >= 2:`

Comment: @Sheldore, sorry, edited code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpacking for the array shape using the `*`

**Defining the function**

```
import numpy as np

def add_batch(arr):
    if arr.ndim >= 2:
        arr = np.reshape(arr, (*arr.shape, 1))
    return arr
```

---

---

**Testing the function**

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (5,6))
print (add_batch(arr).shape)
# (5, 6, 1)

arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (5,6, 7))
print (add_batch(arr).shape)
# (5, 6, 7, 1)
```